# How to share text with image to whats app ios

Tags: ios, swift, share

I am trying to share UIImage with text to other applications.
All works good, but with what's app, i have some troubles.
What's app shares only text without image.

```
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img, NSLocalizedString("text", comment: "")], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```